# Pipeline fails with Invalid namespace string: '//'

Tags: java, namespaces, runtime-error, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

**Context:** A streaming pipeline using dataflow 2.6.0, making use of windows and GroupByKey stages

**What happens:** after a short time, the pipeline keeps launching the following error:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid namespace string: '//'`

Looking at the stack trace, this happens because `StateNamespaces` (https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/runners/core-java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/core/StateNamespaces.java) tries to send an empty namespace string to `CoderUtils.decodeFromBase64`, which creates an uncaught `EOF error`, which itself launches a `CoderException`.

However, this only happens in the cloud. Indeed, looking at the stack trace reveals that dataflow proprietary code is at stake here. (in particular, the direct runner never uses `StateNamespaces`)

Here is the stack trace: (full stack trace here https://pastebin.com/xwh82pYx)

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid namespace string: '//'
        org.apache.beam.runners.core.StateNamespaces.fromString(StateNamespaces.java:270)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.WindmillTimerInternals.windmillTimerToTimerData(WindmillTimerInternals.java:264)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingModeExecutionContext$StepContext.lambda$getNextFiredTimer$1(StreamingModeExecutionContext.java:535)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.Iterators$7.transform(Iterators.java:750)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:47)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingModeExecutionContext$StepContext.getNextFiredTimer(StreamingModeExecutionContext.java:543)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processTimers(SimpleParDoFn.java:445)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processTimers(SimpleParDoFn.java:343)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.finish(ParDoOperation.java:51)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:83)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1227)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1000(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:136)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$6.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:966)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CoderException: java.io.EOFException
        org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.InstantCoder.decode(InstantCoder.java:70)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.InstantCoder.decode(InstantCoder.java:34)
        ...
```

**How can I fix this error ?**

---

Some investigation:

- there seems to be no documentation on similar errors available
- this could be related to [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2831) in the flink runner, however it was supposed to be fixed in beam 2.5.0

Comment: Good start at debugging, but please edit your stack trace into the question itself.